# How to mock Abstract class using Mockito?

Tags: junit, mockito

I am trying to mock abstract class which is called within another class. I mocked the abstract class however mocked abstract class is not being injected.

Any advise on how to mock the abstract class and inject it?

```java
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

public HelloBean getHelloBean(HelloBean bean){
  return bean;
}
}

public class MyBusinessClass extends MyAbstractClass {

public String getBusinessData(){

HelloBean bean = getHelloBean(new HelloBean()) //I want to mock this method while testing getBusinessData()

}

} 


My JUnit Class

public class MyBusinessClass {

private MyAbstractClass myAbstractClass = mock(MyAbstractClass.class);
private MyBusinessClass myBusinessClass = mock(MyBusinessClass.class);


@Test
public String getBusinessData(){

when(myAbstractClass.getHelloBean(any(HelloBean.class))).doReturn(new HelloBean());

myBusinessClass.getBusinessData(); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Inject Mock it works
Here the test class is

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class HelloServiceMockTest {
    @InjectMocks
    MyBusinessClass myBusinessClass;
    
    @Mock
    MyAbstractClass myAbstractClass;
    @Mock
    HelloBean helloBean;
        @Test
        public void getBusinessData(){
        when(myAbstractClass.getHelloBean(helloBean)).thenReturn(new HelloBean());

             myBusinessClass.getBusinessData(); 
          Assert.assertEquals("ggg",myBusinessClass.getBusinessData());
        }
}
```

HelloBean class is

```
public class HelloBean {
    
    public String get()
    {
        return "ggg";   }

}
```

MyBusinessClass is

```
public class MyBusinessClass extends MyAbstractClass {

public String getBusinessData(){

HelloBean bean = getHelloBean(new HelloBean()); //I want to mock this method while testing getBusinessData()
return bean.get();

}
}
```